# Delta-Omega Hedging

Tags: options, hedging, delta-neutral

I am currently trying to understand the in's and out's of options and more specifically hedging. I came across a document that was talking about Delta Hedging which is just making sure the delta of your overall position will be 0. But how do you hedge Omega(Time)?

Comment: Could you please give the reference?

Comment: The Omega Part of Delta-Omega Hedging was defined here. https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:wybMsJjrYggJ:finance.yendor.com/etfviz/2007/0928/Omega-intro.pdf+Keating+and+Shadwick+Omega+ratio&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjTVTLUi5XpI-jEmT_aCxq5S6SzgRTbqQljhCqrH1GdfeS-d5KpEg6fgKVsou6tmRvU9_BKSojjgNhExbUFZQLAg_tWlnyZmyVlj7Tofq0hl1v7SN1zCRCaoYBoXsGGUCQUXJFv&sig=AHIEtbQ0L5KEKcgzGxVYEngeNLBDIAK4Vw

Comment: Is Delta-Omega Hedging another way of saying Delta Neutral, while comparing multiple different delta neutral strategies based upon their Omega ratio?

Comment: Hi ChromoX, welcome to quant.SE.  Please consider registering to help the site track the progress of your question.  Omega is a performance measure, intended as a more sophisticated replacement for the Sharpe ratio.  I have never heard of "delta-omega hedging" or hedging "omega(time)".  Do you have sources for these terms?

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not a real question" due to the concerns above.